# In a CREATE TABLE statment, why "KEY" is used in this way? KEY `IDX_ATTRIBUTE_LABEL_ATTRIBUTE` (`attribute_id`)

Tags: mysql, sql, key

I'm trying to understand this table structure. I never seen this kind of statement, is 
this some kind of *foreign key*?

there's no table like *IDX_ATTRIBUTE_LABEL_ATTRIBUTE*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eav_attribute_label (
  `attribute_label_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_label_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ATTRIBUTE_LABEL_ATTRIBUTE` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ATTRIBUTE_LABEL_STORE` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ATTRIBUTE_LABEL_ATTRIBUTE_STORE` (`attribute_id`,`store_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case KEY is a synonym for INDEX, it is not a foreign key.

Note - index on `attribute_id` is redundant because there is composite index (`attribute_id`,`store_id`).

Comment: Your note is only true because there is also a key on `store_id`. Put another way, if there was no key `store_id` then there could be a legitimate reason for having keys `attribute_id` *and* (`attribute_id`, `store_id`).